# Set Environment Variables using Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have an error reading environment variables to deploy a project in spring with tomcat. Develop the project on Eclipse and set environment variables. When tested in Eclipse everything works fine. But to generate the "war" file and upload it to the server of the variables pointing to an operating system file. Even so this file is not found.

File applicationContext.xml:

```
<property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>file:${FILE_PROPERTIES}</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

I'm using spring and zk as development framework. And I set environment variables in the operating system. That may be wrong settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need a property resolver, recommand you to read more about it.

Old article but quite good:

http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring